# ngResource return success callback result by service

Tags: angularjs, service, promise, ngresource

I have recetly began an adventure with AngularJs but idea of promises and returning asynchonous data overhelmed me.

I am trying to accomplish simple data returining via .factory method and $resource service.

Here is my $resource service returning promise

```
(function () {
        angular.module('token')
            .factory('tokenService', ['$resource', 'baseUri', tokenService]);

        function tokenService($resource, baseUri) {
            return $resource(baseUri + 'token', {}, {
                post: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })();
```

I am using this service in another service which should returns data.

```
(function () {
angular.module('authorization')
    .factory('authorizationService', ['$httpParamSerializer', 'tokenService', authorizationService]);

function authorizationService($httpParamSerializer, tokenService) {
    return {
        authorization: function(user){
            var token = {};
            tokenService.post({}, $httpParamSerializer({
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: user.login,
                password: user.password,
                client_id: user.clientId
            }), function(response){
                token = response;
                console.log('authorizationResponse', response);
                console.log('authorizationToken', token);
            });
            //     .$promise.then(function(response){
            //     token = response;
            //     console.log('authorizationResponse', response);
            //     console.log('authorizationToken', token);
            // });
            console.log('finalToken', token);
            return token;
        }
    };
}
})();
```

But i cannot force token variable to posses tokenService.post() result before returing.

Comment: Short answer, you can't. Your authorizationService will have to return a Promise. There is a draft proposal to add new feature, [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), to the language, but it's a way off.

Answer (score 0):

First: inject `$q` in your `authorizationService`.

Try this:

```
authorization: function(user) {
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    tokenService.post({}, {
      grant_type: 'password',
      username: user.login,
      password: user.password,
      client_id: user.clientId
    })
    .$promise
    .then(function(token) {
      resolve(token);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

Then, in your controller, you can use:

```
authorizationService.authorization(user)
.then(function(token) {
  // Some code here
})
.catch(function(err) {
  // Handle error here
});
```